# how to create a media file (external url image) using the api php client for akeneo?

Tags: image, url, external, media, akeneo

the url of the image can't be read.
this is the code :
';'

```
$data=[];
$url='https://media.but.fr/images_produits/produit-xl/4894223194846_AMB1.jpg';
$client->getProductMediaFileApi()->create($url,$data );
```

I want to know how to use the url of the image with the api php client for akeneo using create function